# Search queries involving symbols and/or $\TeX{}$

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, search

Currently some (most?) fairly crucial symbols such as `=` and `^` are truncated in search queries, making it pretty tough to find questions that have already been asked. It can be overridden to a certain extent by encouraging users to post more descriptive question titles, but there are many occasions when there is no obviously suitable title.

This arose when I was looking for a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199235/) (which is a problem I've seen so many times that it *has* to have a duplicate somewhere!). My search query `m^n=n^m` returned a page entitled *Questions containing 'mnnm'*. Naturally, it returned no results!

Is this something that could be changed?

This is very similar to [this feature request](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1388/) asked in December 2010, which I think is sufficiently long enough ago that I can bring this up again. If nothing can be done, it would be useful if the [search tips](https://math.stackexchange.com/search) page could link to an external resource such as [this one](http://uniquation.com/en/) which allows (web-wide) searches of this nature.

Comment: Maybe some of these links might be useful: [How to search the internet for strings that consist mostly of math notation?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74609/how-to-search-the-internet-for-strings-that-consist-mostly-of-math-notation),
[How do you search for specific questions?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5048/how-do-you-search-for-specific-questions) and
[How do you search for duplicates](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3258/how-do-you-search-for-duplicates).

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Yes, thanks. The external search features like the ones appearing in those questions and the one I linked to are fine as temporary solutions to the problem; but it would be great if the search box on MSE had the same functionality. [Perhaps I'm too ambitious.]

Comment: No, I think you are the right amount of ambitious. But [StackExchange search is pretty bad in more ways than one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45972/152819), and [it's not likely to get any better](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117703#comment308670_117703).

Comment: According to [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6855/i-cant-search-on/7103#7103), it is now possible to search for some special symbols and TeX symbols.

Comment: There's also [searchOnMath](http://www.searchonmath.com/).